# Is it possible to bind to a property name?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, binding, windows-runtime

Is it possible to bind a property name. I seem to come up with run time errors when I try.

For instance:

```
<button Name="{Binding UniqueID}" Click="ButtonHandler">
```

This being in a header for a collection in a grid-view...

Comment: Good question. In theory Name seems to be a DependencyProperty and it should work, but I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't. Have you checked the docs? Also, there might be othervways to debug your runtime exceptions if you have any specific one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.name.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind Name, sorry. It's used for too many things internally and stuff would surely go crazy if you could. The docs are a bit vague, but do say this: (emphasis mine)

> You cannot use the string value of Name as a
>   direct source value for a data binding source. If you have to display
>   the same string value as Name in UI with binding, you should replicate
>   the same value to the Tag property, which can be used as a property
>   binding source. **Also don't use Name as a binding target.**

([MSDN: FrameworkElement.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.name.aspx))

However, if you want to attach random extra data to UI controls, I would recommend using attached properties instead. That way they're specifically associated with what you're doing and will be appropriately typed, unlike Tag.

([MSDN: Custom Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965327.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've read the documentation over and over and cannot find a way to make it work.  The documentation doesn't say you cannot do it, but it doesn't say you can do it either.

However, I found two workarounds.  Instead of binding the name, if you aren't using Tag or DataContect, you can find to those and in the handler extract them by casting as a string.

It's not elegant, but, it does seem to work as expected.